# Determine when CallerRunsPolicy is being exercised

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I have an executor with finite bounds and it uses `CallerRunsPolicy`. So when I submit too many jobs, I encounter a `RejectedExecutionException` and my job gets executed on the calling thread.

Lets assume the job just prints whether it is getting executed on the executor service or on the calling thread. What is the best way of achieving this? Is there any inbuilt visibility into when the job is getting executed on the caller thread?

One possible solution am thinking of is to extend Runnable and CallerRunsPolicy and then override `rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor)` to store a flag within the Runnable.

```
class CustomRunnable implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if(willExecuteOnCallingThread) // Running on new thread.
        else // Running on calling thread.
    }
    boolean willExecuteOnCallingThread = false;
}

class LoggedCallerRunsPolicy extends CallerRunsPolicy
{
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor)
    {
        ((CustomRunnable)r).setWillExecuteOnCallingThread(true);
       super.rejectedExecution(r, executor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit complex but robust solution. Add extra queue (called Q1) ans also thread (called Thr1) between your calling thread & executors. Calling thread just add to Q1, Thr1 consumes to Q1 and give job to executorservice. executorservice make extra operation after complete own job that notify to your Thr1 thread. Thr1 will notify and fetch from Q1 put to ExecutorService task.

Answer (score 0):

The API does not provide a built-in method for getting that information, simply because you shouldn’t write tasks that depend in any way on the executing thread.

If you still insist on recording that information, using a specialized `RejectedExecutionHandler` is a proper way, however, you shouldn’t set a flag on the `Runnable`. In principle, a `Runnable` can be queued multiple times and even executed by multiple threads at the same time. It might even be the case that it is executed by one pooled thread and by one caller thread at the same time.

After all, you don’t need mutable state nor conditionals to implement it:

```
class CustomRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("executed by pool thread");
        actualAction();
    }
    public void callerRun() {
        System.out.println("executed by submitting (aka caller) thread");
        actualAction();
    }
    private void actualAction() {
        // … perform your action independently of the executing thread
    }
}

class LoggedCallerRunsPolicy implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        if(r instanceof CustomRunnable)
            ((CustomRunnable)r).callerRun();
        else
            r.run();
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that this works only if the `CustomRunnable` has been queued using `execute`. If the runnable has been queued by `submit`, it will be wrapped into a `RunnableFuture` and that wrapper is the object passed to either, the queue or the `RejectedExecutionHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

The most primitive way is using Thread.currentThread().getName().
Notice: using MyThreadImpl.getName() leads to another result.

```
class CustomRunnable implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        log.info("Executed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```